# Divergence of an integral related to a Riemann integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{x} & \;\text{if }\; x < -1 \\
 0 & \;\text{if }\;-1\le  x\le 1 \\
 \dfrac{1}{x} & \;\text{if }\; x> 1 \\
\end{cases}$

I wanted to show that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\;dx$ does not converge.

I know that $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges  (Riemann integral) by showing that $\displaystyle\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{1}^{R}f(x)dx=\infty$. And I can compute the limit  $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to -\infty}\int_{r}^{-1}f(x)dx=-\infty$ and that $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=0$ but what about the sum of these integrals
$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$, knowing that the sum of divergent integrals may converge.

Comment: K.defaoite has given the correct answer. What you seem to be referring to is an entirely different kind of integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: Thanks! is the mean of a continuous random variable $X$ with pdf $f(x)$ given by $Mean=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\;dx$ defined as a Cauchy principal value? I think it is because I read that if the pdf $f(x)$ is an even function then the mean is zero.

Comment: No, the Cauchy principal value may exist, but if the integral is not convergent the mean does not exist. See for instance this, about the Cauchy distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Mean

Answer (score 2):

Each integral needs to converge separately. As a **definition**,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx=\lim_{A\to -\infty}\lim_{B\to \infty} \int_A^B f(x)\mathrm dx$$
Since neither of these limits exist for our $f$, the integral is divergent.